# Generating a Database from SQL script in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I was recently given a project using ASP.NET, C#, and an SQL database. I am somewhat familiar with ASP.NET and C#, however I have never used the Microsoft database software in visual studio. I simply need to generate a database from an SQL script given to me. I was able to get the database mostly generated, however some of the code (The part adding items to one of the tables) did not run on execution. I have tried adding other scripts and rerunning the first one, I cannot get anything to work. I know the script is fine, I just cant get it to run correctly. Thanks for the help. Here's the script

```
/*These first few lines don't run */
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductNote](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoteText] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [Archived] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductNote] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductNote]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductNote_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [Product] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductNote] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductNote_Product]
GO

/*This part does not run either */
DECLARE @n INT = 1
WHILE (@n <=20)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Name) SELECT 'Product ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@n)
    SET @n = @n + 1
END

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio
Go to View->Solution Explorer
Then Connect your sql Data Base
following links might be helpfull ro connect your db in visual studio
1.http://support.webecs.com/kb/a204/how-do-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-visual-studio-_net.aspx
2.https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/SQL-Server-Connecting-to-your-database-through-code-or-Visual-StudioNET

Expand your DB then Right Click on Stored Procedure -> Add new stored procedure
Replace all text with your script->Select All->Right Click ->Run Selection
That's it.